# Reading and Writing LONGTEXT from MariaDB in Lotus Notes Server-Agent on SuSE Linux via unixODBC

Tags: mysql, lotusscript, unixodbc

I am trying to read and write LONGTEXT columns from a mariaDB table in an LotusScript Server-Agent.

I use an ODBCConnection and ODBCResultset to do this.

I try to write a SQL query like this:

```
select *   
from ticket 
where ...
```

If I do this, the result set knows how many columns are in the table and the datatypes are known.

But if I try to get a value from the table by using

```
result.GetValue('FieldName')
```

I get an error

> LS:DO- The result contains no data

If I change the SQL query to this:

```
select field1, field2, ... 
from ticket 
where ...
```

and no LONGTEXT column is used in the query, everything is great and I can read and write data to the table.

Does anyone have a hint for me, what could I do to get it working?

Thanks!

Marcus

Comment: LONGTEXT can be as large as 4GB -- it is like a Notes rich text field.  I doubt this will work in an ODBC connection as is.  You'll have to convert the LONGTEXT value to text -- it can be HTML or MIME if you want all the elements passed as text.